# Архитектура Laravel с админкой, CRM и клиентом

Tags: php, laravel, архитектура

Всем привет. Сейчас есть приложение на Laravel, где есть админка и клиентская часть. Вход в админку идет через обычный `/admin`, для нее сделано отдельное пространство имен `App\Controllers\Admin`. Авторизации на клиентской части нет, поэтому админка работает через дефолтную авторизацию.

Вопрос заключается в том, что по мере расширения функционала, будет довольно громоздко держать админку, CRM и клиентскую часть вместе. Более того, CRM система должна быть надежной и при любой атаке на клиентскую часть, она должна функционировать исправно.

Скажите, каким образом лучше всего построить архитектуру в данном случае, правильно ли я делаю? Не будет ли лучше разбить это на 3 независимые части, а CRM-систему вовсе вынести на отдельный сервер? Если да, то как брать данные с сервера, где лежит информация о товарах и т.д.? Если это делать через API, то это довольно большая нагрузка, поскольку каждый заказ автоматически связывается с ID товара через таблицу `order_products`, из-за этого мне придется делать 1 запрос на каждый из товаров заказа?

Сейчас каша в голове, а по архитектуре ничего хорошего в просторах интернета не нашел, что могло бы конкретно в моем случае пригодиться. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: разбить на разные системы - идея хорошая. Но почему ты думаешь, что придется делать 1 запрос на каждую позицию товара? Сам проектируешь API - сам решай, какие данные оно будет отдавать. Ты можешь на 1 запрос заказа от CRM выдавать весь объект заказа с коллекцией товаров или товарных модицикаций

Answer (score 1):

По такому простому описанию однозначно сказать как лучше — сложно. Но есть ряд советов:

> Авторизации на клиентской части нет, поэтому админка работает через
>   дефолтную авторизацию.

Если смотреть о том, как безопаснее — прежде всего не следует использовать популярные пути для админки `/admin` и авторизации. Это первое куда лезут недоброжелатели при поиске уязвимостей. Поэтому лучше что-то нетривиальное, типа того же `/sitecontrol`, или вообще какого-нибудь имени собственного.

> Не будет ли лучше разбить это на 3 независимые части, а CRM-систему
>   вовсе вынести на отдельный сервер?

CRM, на мой взгляд, можно было бы вынести в субдомен (а лучше домен, закрытый от индексации), и на отдельный хостинг. Чтобы немного сэкономить ресурсы и фукционал — можно было бы сделать два подключения с БД из CRM: одно для нужд CRM с её собственной БД, другое для работы с моделями основного сайта (например, с заказами и товарами, чтобы полностью не дублировать информацию).

При этом нужно проработать взаимодействие основного сайта и CRM системы, чтобы по возможности сэкономить на трафике и нагрузке, но не во вред читаемости и понятности всей архитектуры. Где возможно — формировать запросы со стороны сайта и передавать их в CRM (Например, при добавлении заказа на сайте — уведомлять CRM о событии и там формировать нужные записи), где нужно — выстраивать работу и обращения к основному сайту из CRM системы.

Отдельной темой будет сопровождение одного и того же клиента, но это уже зависит от самих бизнес процессов, скорее, нежели от архитектуры вашего решения.